# How can I find $f ^{−1}(3)$ for $f(x) = x^7 + x + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function is $f(x) = x^7 + x + 1$.

How can you find the inverse of this function to begin with, and then proceed to finding a value at that inverse? I know that the function is increasing so the inverse does exist(and it's domain is every number), but I"m not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: For ugly functions, sometimes the best method is to just try a few values, starting with easy ones. $0$ doesn't work, but $f(1) = 3$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(3) = 1$.

Comment: Guess 1. Check and verify it is 1.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get a nice "closed form" for the inverse.  There are  solutions involving various special functions, but you probably don't want to go there.  Rational solutions to $f(x) = y$ when $y$ is rational (if they exist) can be found with the help of the Rational Roots Theorem.  For any $y$, you can use numerical methods such as Newton's method to get an approximation of the solution.

In the case $y=3$, $f(x) - y = x^7 + x - 2$.  The Rational Roots Theorem says that any rational solution must be an integer that divides $-2$.  The candidates are $-2,\; -1,\; 0,\; 1,\; 2$, and it's easy to check which one works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to find the inverse of the function - $f^{-1}(x)$.

Just notice that $f^{-1}(3)$ equals the value of $x$ when you solving
$$x^7+x+1=3$$
Notice that $x=1$ is a solution.
So $$f^{-1}(3)=1$$
Actually this equation have 7 solutions if you want to solve it in complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A closed form solution of a general polynomial of degree greater than 5 is provably impossible. In this case, there is no very nice inverse for such a function. I'm assuming your teacher was hoping you could do some trial and error and find the answer:

You want $f^{-1}(3)$. This is equivalent to finding an $a$ such that $f(a) = 3$. With a bit of trial and error, you can see $f(1) = 3$ and so $f^{-1}(3) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^7+x+1$ is increasing, because $f'(x)=7x^6+1>0$. Thus $f^{-1}(3)$ consists of at most one point, precisely the unique (real) solution of
$$
x^7+x+1=3
$$
Since clearly $f(1)=3$, you have your answer.

It's by no mean strange that the inverse is not expressible in terms of “elementary functions”. This is one case.